# function to increment / decrement more than stepper in javascript

Tags: javascript

Hello I am trying to rewrite a function that will increment / decrement more than 1 stepper in javascript. Here is what I tried so far

here is a codepen link http://codepen.io/Ongomobile/pen/XdyBgv/

Here is 1 of the steppers

```
<div class="qtyDiv">
        <label class="qtyLabel" for="qty1 " name"one"><abbr title="Quantity">Qty</abbr></label>
        <input class="qtyInput" id="qty1" value="0" name"one" />            
        <!-- <button class=" tallyBtn" id="down" onclick="modify_qty(-1)">-1</button>
        <button class="tallyBtn"id="up" onclick="modify_qty(1)">+1</button> -->
        <button class=" tallyBtn" id="down" onclick="stepperVal("one",-1)">-1</button>
        <button class="tallyBtn"id="up" onclick="stepperVal("one",1)">+1</button>
</div>

// This is current one
function modify_qty(val) {
  var qty = document.querySelector("#qty1").value;

  var new_qty = parseInt(qty,10) + val;

  if (new_qty < 0) {
    new_qty = 0;
  }

  document.querySelector("#qty1").value = new_qty;

  return new_qty;
}
```

This is what I tried

```
function stepperVal(name,val){
  var qty = 0;
  var new_qty = parseInt(qty,10) + val;

  if (new_qty < 0) {
    new_qty = 0;
  }
  [name].value = new_qty;
  return new_qty;
}
```

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: Why do you think that replacing `document.querySelector("#qty1")` with `[name]` would even come close to working?

Comment: Thanks Anthony sorry I was trying to format correctly but you beat me to it.

Comment: I am real new just bang around but trying to learn

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol I think that's just a placeholder, right?

Comment: that is what I was thinking

Comment: I guess I'm just confused why you'd use `querySelector` when you can just do `document.getElementById('qty1')`, but more confused that you didn't try `document.getElementById(name)` and pass the target element's ID to the function...

Comment: I will try `getElementById(name)

Answer (score 1):

Use following it must work:

```
function stepperVal(name,val){
var qty = 0;
var new_qty = parseInt(document.getElementsByName(name),10) + val;

  if (new_qty < 0) {
   new_qty = 0;
   }
  document.getElementsByName(name).value = new_qty;
return new_qty;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A few issues:

- What's the purpose of this line `parseInt(qty,10) + val;`? `parseInt` is intended to convert a string into its equivalent digit. Not much point in calling it on a base10 number.
- Not sure what the point of the name argument to `stepperVal` is. Isn't the amount to be stepped already implied by the `value` argument?
- You can pass a reference to the object triggering the `onclick` event by passing `this` to your function declared within the `onclick`.
- `new_qty` always evaluates to `val`
- `stepperVal(arg,-1)` is actually the same as `stepperVal(arg,0)`. Why not just call it that way?

**Updated code**

replace "one" with `this` in :

```
<div class="qtyDiv">
        <label class="qtyLabel" for="qty1 " name"one"><abbr title="Quantity">Qty</abbr></label>
        <input class="qtyInput" id="qty1" value="0" name"one" />            
        <!-- <button class=" tallyBtn" id="down" onclick="modify_qty(-1)">-1</button>
        <button class="tallyBtn"id="up" onclick="modify_qty(1)">+1</button> -->
        <button class=" tallyBtn" id="down" onclick="stepperVal(this,-1)">-1</button>
        <button class="tallyBtn"id="up" onclick="stepperVal(this,1)">+1</button>
</div>
```

**Simplified JS:**

```
function stepperVal(event, val){    
  clicked_link = event.target
  return clicked_link.value = Math.max(0, val);  # Return the greater of 0 and `val`
}
```

Comment: Thanks @AnthonyE I tried what you suggested got this error in console estimate.js:38 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'value' of undefined